# PySmbClient unlink: Error: sequence item 0: expected a bytes-like object, str found

Tags: python, samba

I'm using PySmbClient library to do operations on NAS

```
from smbclient import SambaClient
from airflow.hooks.samba_hook import SambaHook

def smbconnect(**kwargs):    
    smbconn = kwargs['smbconn']    
    smb_hook = SambaHook(samba_conn_id = smbconn)
    return smb_hook.get_conn()


def run(**kwargs):
    smb = smbconnect(**kwargs)
    f = smb.open(filePath, "r")

    # Some operations

    smb.unlink(filePath) # I'm getting error at this line
```

Error message is

```
Error: sequence item 0: expected a bytes-like object, str found
```

I'm a bit confused on why the parameter filePath has problem.
The function signature for `open` and `unlink` in the library is as follows:

```
def open(self, path, mode='r'):
    """
    Opens the file indicated by path and returns it as a file-like
    object
    """
    f = _SambaFile(self, path, mode)
    self._open_files[f] = (path, mode)
    return f


def unlink(self, path):
    """Removes/deletes/unlinks a file"""
    path = path.replace('/', '\\')
    self._runcmd_error_on_data(u'del', path)
remove = unlink
```

Why is passing `filePath` to `path` works in `open` function but not `unlink`? How to resolve the issue?

[Edit]: Added traceback

```
[2021-07-05 03:45:02,633] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/dags/PythonScript_Pipeline.py", line 103, in load_function
    smb.unlink(filePath)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/smbclient.py", line 362, in unlink
    self._runcmd_error_on_data(u'del', path)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/smbclient.py", line 191, in _runcmd_error_on_data
    raise SambaClientError("Error on %r: %r" % (b' '.join(cmd).decode('utf8'), data))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected a bytes-like object, str found
```

Comment: Can you post the complete traceback?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM Added

Comment: What is `smb`?  That variable is not shown in the script.

Comment: @JohnGordon Added